# Installing python 2.7.11 on shared hosting gives permission denied

Tags: python, bluehost, python-install

I am following [this guideline](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install) to install python 2.7.11 on a CentOs shared hosting (bluehost). 
I get the following error during the **make install** phase:

```
(cd /home2/some_user/python/bin; ln -s python2 python)
ln: creating symbolic link `python': Permission denied
make: *** [bininstall] Error 1
```

Anywhere in the guideline mentioned 2.7.2 I changed it to 2.7.11. 
A few hours back I had installed 2.7.2 with no issues. I get this error when installing 2.7.11.

How can I skip this error and continue with installation of 2.7.11?

Or if there are better ways to install python 2.7.11 on shared hosting it's ok to change method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this trick solved the issue:

```
cd /home2/some_user/python/bin; 
cp python2.7 python2
```

So basically I got the error when running make install, ran above commands to trick the installation there is a python2 folder exists, and then reran the make install and python was installed successfully.

Most likely in previous installations python2 was just "python2", not python2.7.

Also [here](http://simplyargh.blogspot.com/2012/04/python-27-django-14-on-bluehost.html) is a better document discussing how to install python 2.7, and for installing 2.7.11 just change all 2.7.2 to 2.7.11. But still running this will give the above error and should do the trick to bypass the error.